# Modify existing Azure policy to white list the new features for the resources provisioned

Tags: azure, azure-policy

When we created a landing zone a year before we created some policies to white list some of the features of some services like key vault, VMs etc.  After a year Microsoft would have released some extra features in the resources we provisioned earlier.  Those features will not be available for the users because the existing policy does not white list the new features available.  We need to modify our policy using code to white list the new features which are released by the Microsoft.  Key vault is one example where we need to white list all the new features in all the resources deployed in our environment.

Answer (score 0):

You did not post your policy, so it is a bit of guessing here.
If you are using the `built-in policy` named `Allowed Resource Types` found here:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-policy/blob/master/built-in-policies/policyDefinitions/General/AllowedResourceTypes_Deny.json

Then you do not need to worry about this.
From what I read, you are using `"mode": "All"`, which is **not** a good approach when whitelisting.

```
Get-AzResourceProvider -ListAvailable |
Where-Object ProviderNameSpace -match "Microsoft" |
Where-Object ProviderNameSpace -notmatch "Classic" |
Where-Object RegistrationState -eq "NotRegistered" |
Select-Object ProviderNamespace, RegistrationState, Locations
```

Comment: Actually this is my requirment:

Comment: We have whitelisted most of the services and did not whitelist few services. Get-Azresourceprovider command treats all the whitelisted services as "NotRegistered" in the command output if few sub services are not whitelisted But most of the services are whitelisted. I need some help to get only the output which are not registered and registered. Looks like Get-azresourceprovider command treats one service as Notregistered if one of the component is not whitelisted. For Microsoft.SQL there are plenty of services and we whitelisted most and few are not Azure treats entire SQL service as NotRegis

Comment: It is confusing that you talk about a PowerShell command, when you originally asked to modify an existing policy. You should post the policy that you have if you expect people to help you - just an advice. I edited my answer with a PowerShell script that will give you which resource provider is missing. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/troubleshooting/error-register-resource-provider?tabs=azure-cli